# Firebug Disabled on Some Sites?

Tags: firebug

I have noticed on some website that firebug is off while on other sites it is on. I have not made any changes to these settings but how does a site tell firebug to turn off or how does firebug know do not turn on for this site?

Comment: This is why I don't use Firebug any more. I reported it as a bug but apparently it's meant to pop up randomly all over the place.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - I found an option when looking (after posting this question) that allows me to turn firebug on for all sites. I am using the latest version 1.9.0b1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebug remembers which sites you used it for. Here's an example. Go to a website and turn Firebug on. Now close out. Then, go to my site, www.mitchseymour.com (I'm using my site because I highly doubt you have ever been there before). Firebug should not be active. Now, revisit the site you just used FB on, and it should show up again.

Hope this helps.